# why setText for textView add text bottom of textView?

Tags: ios, xcode, textview, uitextview

I'm noob in objective c and I create one page xib file that this page have one textView empty.
I drag UITextView ton this page and connect to self outlet.
Now I want to add any text like this "I AM JANATAN" in it. when I using this code and run my simulator , my simulator show me my textView but I see my sentence is last line of textView !!!
why??? this is my image : [pic of simulator](http://i59.tinypic.com/29n9t2f.png)

this is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    getTextPlaces = [self CreateTextViews];
    textField1 = [getTextPlaces objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:textField1];

    NSString *str = [_stack pop];
    textArray = [self readInformationFromDatabaseWithData:str];
    NSString *s1 = [[textArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Names"];
    textField1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",s1]; //this s1 value is I am janatan
}
- (NSMutableArray *)CreateTextViews{
    UITextView *tf = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 70, 250, 50)];
    tf.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    tf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
    tf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    tf.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    //tf.text=@"Hello World";

    //second one
    UITextView *tf1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, tf.frame.origin.y + 70, 250, 50)];
    tf1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
    tf1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    tf1.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    tf1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    //and so on adjust your view size according to your needs
    NSMutableArray *twoText = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [twoText addObject:tf];
    [twoText addObject:tf1];

    return twoText;

}
```

Comment: You should include the code that produces this problem with your question.

Comment: @EsaLakaniemi thanks my friend I added my code!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend for remove this you need is to set the following:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

in the viewDidLoad method.